# How to Query Custom Fields Which are not part of Enterprise WSDL in Salesforce?

Tags: soql, soap-api, integration, standard-objects, .net

I'm Querying Contact object From .Net but I'm unable to Capture the result.
We've added some custom fields to Contact Object after Importing Enterprise WSDL in .NET. But I'm unable to capture the new custom field values because my WSDL doesn't contain new Custom fields.

> Salesforce.Contact c = (Salesforce.Contact)salesforce.query(query).records[0];

Any one please tell me how to capture all fields without updating the enterprise wsdl(Query has been executing Succesfully!)

Answer (score 1):

According to your questions you created the fields AFTER consuming the wsdl so......

Have you tried generating a new WSDL and consuming it on the .net end? That would be how you do it. Otherwise there is NO way using the WSDL.

You could use SOAP or REST API to perform the query and not utilize the wsdl at all if you must stick by your requirement of NOT generating the WSDL again. Then you can parse thorough the response manually in the code without the assistance of the WSDL

Comment: He would also have the ability to consume the Partner WSDL which is dynamic.  Would take a major code change, but may be worth it!